# Default value doesn't work in sqlalchemy automap

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Suppose I have table `main_table` with columns:

```
id (AUTO_INCREMENT), first (int), value1 (double with default=0), value2 (double)
```

Using code

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(db_connect)
session = Session(engine)
base = automap_base()
base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
table = getattr(base.classes, fact_table)
kwargs = {'first': 200016, 'value2': 1.0}
entry = table(**kwargs)
session.add(entry)
session.commit()
```

I got an error `{"error": 500, "message": "(pymysql.err.IntegrityError) (1048, \"Column 'value1' cannot be null\")`

It happens when `value1` doesn't accept `null` value.

I'd like to ignore this and add entry after all value1 is not obligatory (has default).

`SHOW CREATE TABLE main_table;`:

```
CREATE TABLE `main_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value1` double(22,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.000000,
  `value2` double(22,6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=200000 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: If you believe that this is a deficiency in automap please open a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues).

Comment: @snakecharmerb of course I forgot about the most important last line. `session.commit()`. I added it. `value1` shouldn't accept `null`.

Comment: I have Mariadb 10.5.5 and Python 3.8, I use `mysql+pymysql` (db_connect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with SQLAlchemy 1.3.20 (and previous) + MariaDB. Resolved here:

https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5744

Comment: Yes, it's my issue. :)